# Change DataGridView row color based on current date

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control with `Date` column. I want to set the color for each row based on the value in this column compared to the current day:

If date in my grid is at least 15 days away, leave the default color. If the date in my grid is only 5 days away, use an ORANGE color. If the date is only 1 day way, use a RED color.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `CellFormatting` event for datagridview and within it check if it's the desired column, check its value against `DateTime.Now` and change this cells `Style.BackColor`.

Answer (score 0):

Create two functions, one from going through all rows and other for coloring all cells in row.

```
private void ColorDates()
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Datagridview is empty!");
        return;
    }

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        DateTime value = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["DateColumn"].Value);
        DateTime citeria = new DateTime(2018, 28, 02);

        int result = DateTime.Compare(value, citeria);

        if (result < 0) //value is earlier than citeria
            ColorRow(row, Color.Red);
        else if (result == 0) //Value is equal to citeria
            ColorRow(row, Color.Green);
        else if (result > 0) //value is later than citeria
            ColorRow(row, Color.Blue);
    }
}

private void ColorRow(DataGridViewRow row, Color color)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cell.Style.BackColor = color;
    }
}
```

You call it after you bind data to datagridview with `ColorDates()`